# Keep getting a Index was outside the bounds of the array error Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I keep getting a "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error when trying to run my code. It points to this line.

```
If order(i).purchaseMethod = "S" Then
```

It is in this context

```
Sub calculatePopularPayment(ByRef popularMethod, ByVal order)
    'declares the subclass-specific variables
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim officeCount As Integer = 0
    Dim websiteCount As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To 299
        If order(i).purchaseMethod = "S" Then
            officeCount = officeCount + 1
        ElseIf order(i).purchaseMethod = "W" Then
            websiteCount = websiteCount + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Does your array have 300 elements?

Comment: @BrianMStafford yes it does

Comment: You are in a for loop using i, yet you increment i manually.

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't notice the manual increment.

Comment: Do you have a reason to be writing this code to be late-bound ? If you know the type of the passed arguments, then specify it in the method signature.  It will make your life much simpler in the long run.  Enable "Option Strict".

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line.  What is the value of `i` when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 3):

A [`For`-loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) does not need to be incremented manually, the loop itself odes it for you:

```
For i = 0 To 299
    If order(i).purchaseMethod = "S" Then
        officeCount = officeCount + 1
    ElseIf order(i).purchaseMethod = "W" Then
        websiteCount = websiteCount + 1
    End If
Next
```

Of course this will still throw this exception if there are less than 300 items in the array. If you want to iterate all items you should use:

```
For i = 0 To order.Length - 1
  ...
Next
```

If you want to skip every other element you should use `Step`:

```
For i = 0 To 299 Step 2
   ....
Next
```

Side-note: i strongly recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On`.